# How to update the Progress bar inside Custamized Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Am using Customized Circular progress bar inside the customized list view(Each Row of the listview have one Text-view and Progress bar). The progress bar reduces from **Waiting Time** like count down, My idea is to use **CountDownTimer** but not able to know how to use it in Customized Listview.Can any one know help me to solve this issue.

**Adapter Class**

```
public class Order_adp extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<Order_Model> list;
Activity activity;

public Order_adp(Activity activity, ArrayList<Order_Model> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;

}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {

    TextView order_number, remaining_time;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progrescustom_layout_file, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.order_number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressBar);
        holder.remaining_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    float fraction = Integer.valueOf(list.get(position).getwaiting_time())*1000 / (float) Integer.valueOf(list.get(position).getwaiting_time())*1000;
    holder.progressBar.setMax( (int) (fraction * 100) );
    holder.progressBar.setProgress(100);
    holder.order_number.setText(list.get(position).getorder_number());
    /*CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(Integer.valueOf(list.get(position).getwaiting_time())*1000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            int secondsRemaining = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            float fraction = millisUntilFinished / (float) (Integer.valueOf(list.get(position).getwaiting_time())*1000);
            holder.progressBar.setProgress ( (int) (fraction * 100) );
            holder.remaining_time.setText(secondsRemaining+" more");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            holder.remaining_time.setText("Finished");
        }
    }.start();
    timer.start();*/

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

From the waiting time to reduce the time show it `holder.remaining_time` and update the progress bar `holder.progressBar`. Progress bar reduced from `100%` to `0%`

Comment: try comparing list.size with the position in the getView method and update the progress bar accordingly..

Comment: @GokulKulkarni Cant get you.Can you Explain it Clearly.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time I mistook the question, I'll let u know if I get good suggestions.